# Need help in URL rewriting htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hi everyone,
            I need help regarding URL Rewriting My actual url is `{www.mysub.domain.com/other?Name=Some Product Name&code=12312312}` After adding codes in .htaccess file url would be `{www.mysub.domain.com/other/Some Product Name/12312312}`. This is working fine on my localhost but giving error on my domain host. Below is my codes, Review it and let me know is error. I appreciate your help.

```
<pre>
RewriteEngine on<br>
RewriteRule ^itm/([A-Za-z0-9\s+!@$%&*._%+-/\(){}#='"`~|;:<>]+)/([0-9]+)$ itm.php?ItemName=$1&code=$2<br>
</pre>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Note than you must produce a url with blank spaces! www.mysub.domain.com/other/Some Product Name/12312312. It can produces errors

Comment: Has your production server activated the mod_rewrite module? You can know it uploading a file with a php_info()

Comment: Hi everyone thanks for your response. I check rewrite_mode status on my hosting but unfortunately it is off. I contact to hosting company for enable it they said to me try to on it by placing php.ini file. When i tried i am successfully able to process url but they ignore all other setting i.e {DOCUMENT_ROOT} etc ... How i can resolve it any suggestion plz.

Comment: Finally i got it working. The only problem is remained, i have an page where i want to load content by jquery without reload the page. The Problem is when i write url like {http://www.mydomain.com/itm?Name=Decorative-Antique-Design-Telephones&code=120511025938313} content are loading successfully but content are not loading with rewrite url like this {http://www.mydomain.com/itm/Decorative-Antique-Design-Telephones/120511025938313}. Any suggestion plz. What i need have to change in htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)$ index.php?action=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(member)-([0-9-]+)$ index.php?action=member&id=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)/([a-zA-Z-]+)-([0-9-]+)$ index.php?action=$1&saction=$2&sid=$3 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9-]+)$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/(.*).html$ index.php?action=details&id=$1&p1=$2&p2=$3&p3=$4 [NC,L]
```